# Title bar icons missing in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017

Tags: macos, adobe-illustrator, title-bar

I recently opened up Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 on my Mac to find that my whole topbar is missing. On a Mac, there's a little bar of icons on every application, here's what it *should* look like:

[image]

The problem is, Illustrator on my computer doesn't seem to have on anymore, making it impossible to drag, resize, or close Illustrator conveniently:

[image]

It's all stuck on one monitor (I have two monitors). I've tried switching screen modes via the F key which didn't work. None of the modes had a draggable titlebar with icons.

I've also tried resetting my preferences by deleting my preferences file. That didn't work either, and I've also tried unchecking Window > Application Frame but the view looks totally different. I just want a titlebar on top the application bar that allows me to close, resize, drag, etc.

One thing to note is that I did recently update my Adobe products, and that my workspace all of sudden was different, as in the guides in the margin were gone I don't have a bar to navigate between open files. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're in Adobe's FullScreen mode - rather than Apple's

Standard key is F to toggle modes, next would be full black background, then the 3rd would be back to regular 'windowed'.
The 'tool' itself should be the bottom of the sidebar, highlighted below in red...

[image]
<sup>pic from Photoshop, not Illustrator</sup>

If you can't make the window span more than one monitor, that may be the way you have Spaces set up.
System Prefs > Mission Control > 'Displays have separate Spaces' must be *off* for spanning to work.

Comment: Huh! I went through F about 1000 times before I realized my window was just off the screen so the top was missing! I can't believe I missed that! The button on the sidebar really helped!